# How to add additional text on Drupal contact us page?

Tags: php, drupal, contacts

I've basic drupal site and my client requested put some information top of the contact form eg : tel, email and a small description. I'm trying to figure out how to do that ? I couldn't see in Drupal admin that we can add some text in the contact us page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option would be a block. You can create a custom block, put in your text, and have it show up only on the contact page. Although, depending on the regions defined in your theme, that might end you up having the information above the title of the contact page or below the form.

Comment: This works great. But there are two regions in my template available that I can put.
 1. Content Top
 2. Content

If I put into content top block it'll diaplay before the breadcrumbs and If I put into content block it's displaying below the contact form. Can you please tell me how I can I order the display or any other options ?re two regions available that I can put.

Comment: The regions are defined in your theme, so they can be very different. You should be able to change the place a region appears in your theme's page.tpl.php (search for the region's name inside the file). For example, you could put the breadcrumbs above the region. But remember that that affects the place of the region on every page, not just the contact page.

Comment: Since I'm not using for content_top for other pages this change works fine. But since this is not the proper way I still curios to know what's good way to this.

Comment: I think it is a "proper way", you just need to be aware of the effects it can have - as I said, not just on the contact page, but on every page.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default contact template implementing `page--contact.tpl.php` in your theme.

More info: http://drupal.org/node/1089656

Comment: Well actually I tried above settings but, it's not working. I've created the following file in themes/test/template/page--contact.tpl.php and for testing purpose I've placed the php die; statement in the file. Unfortunately it's not dieing and it's still shows the default contact form. Could you please tell me how to resolve this ?

Comment: Which base theme are you using?

Comment: I've actually downloaded one call News Theme.

Answer (score 0):

You can add text above the contact form through the settings page at /admin/build/contact/settings.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But above your path is redirecting me to the admin home page.

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry, that was for Drupal 6. It seems that the option isn't there anymore in Drupal 7.